# Query in returning Objects from List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List Say foo, which holds data of type Class A (containing members FName, LName, Total).  I need to get the list of datas whose LName is "foobar".

I know this sounds a simple question, but this pisses me off! because the I will get the Members for returning the list in runtime.

Thanks in advance

EDIT : 
I am sorry Geeks, the List is Dyanamic the List is of Object type.  I knows its of type Class A only during runtime

Comment: Show your full code..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can be easily done using LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;

(...)

List<A> foo = GetFooList();    // gets data
List<A> fooBorItems = foo.Where(a = > a.FName == "foobar").ToList();
```

Or using syntax based query:

```
List<A> fooBorItems = (from a in foo
                       where a.FName == "foobar"
                       select a).ToList();
```

For `List<object>` use `Cast<T>` extension method first. It will cast all source collection elements into `A` (and throw exception when it's not possible):

```
List<A> fooBorItems = foo.Cast<A>().Where(a = > a.FName == "foobar").ToList();
```

or `OfType<A>` (which will return only elements that can be casted, without exceptions for these that can't):

```
List<A> fooBorItems = foo.OfType<A>().Where(a = > a.FName == "foobar").ToList();
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mentiion the List is Dyanamic the List is of Object type.  I knows its of type Class A only during runtime

Comment: Thanks for your response Marcin, a.FName can't be used - as the List is of Object type, and I will have FName as String.

Comment: It can be used after `Cast<A>()` or `OfType<A>`, because they both returns `IEnumerable<A>`